# I can run python script by local code of dot net core but when I host the same code on my local machine it does not run python script

Tags: python, .net-core, iis-8

[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5NO9.jpg)I am using dot net core web API it runs python script if i locally debug the code.But when I host my web API on my local machine only Python script is not working rest all are working fine.

```
var file = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DE.PythonPath");
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = file;
        start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Process process = Process.Start(start)
StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput
var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return result;
```

I want to run python script by hosted code.

Comment: What error (if any) do you get? And first things first, do you have Python installed locally?

Comment: Basic rules are https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: @grooveplex I don't get any error in hosted API I got status code 200 ok but the problem is "Failed to load response data" no response

Comment: @grooveplex yes I installed it thats why i can run the code locally without hosting i can debug the code.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks but it is not helpful.

Comment: Could you please tell me which asp.net core application you have used now? Razor page or MVC? How you call this codes? In action method or else? If possbile, please post the details codes about your controller and python scripts to let me reproduce your issue.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I am using MVC.                      I am not able to send full code here neither in post nor in comment but i wrote a piece of code in my question.

Comment: You could directly edit your question with updated codes.

Comment: @BrandoZhang I added an image name Code image where my full code is showing please see.